# How does cloud FireStore read count work?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

This is image of my project where is only one map1 document
inside the document multiple map object

[image: This is image of my project where is only one map1 document inside the document multiple map object]

when I fetch data only map1 document then my read count increased 25 times sometimes 18.

So my question is that why is increasing like this?

And second thing that I read fireStore document where mentioned that
according to your Number of document is return by query as read count increase.

Comment: Sir but my question is that in my document only one document (map1) and I read one time only by clicking on button then how the read count is increasing like 25 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second question first:

The read count you refer to is called **document read count**. As that name implies it is increment by one for every document that is read on the server on your behalf. So if you request a numner of documents from the server, you will be charged for that many *document reads*.

---

The first question is harder to say, because we have no way of reproducing the issue based on your post. But the most common cause of unexpected reads for folks new to Firestore is keeping the Firebase console open.

If you have the Firestore console open, it also reads documents; and those are charged *document reads* too.